# Insert a CloudFormation ImportValue similar to how you can insert a Parameter?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cloudformation, amazon-iam

We have a huge VPC CF Template that we use to define our development, staging, and production environments.  One of these resources is a Common S3 bucket for use with tasks not directly related to a specific customer.  This bucket has an Export named `VPCCommonBucket` which contains just the bucket name.

I am trying to use this Export value in another stack, referencing that bucket, creating an IAM user that has access to ONLY that bucket, further restricting it to a single directory IN that bucket.

When using a Parameter, I can do something like this:

```
!Sub "arn:aws:s3:::${BucketName}/prefix/*"
```

But I cannot find something similar with regard to using `Fn::ImportValue`/`!ImportValue`.  Is there a way to insert an exported variable into a string as I'm trying to do here?  Or is this a matter of needing to go back and alter our main Template to include ANOTHER Export for the Bucket's arn?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are able to use **Fn::ImportValue** in conjunction with **!Sub** in cloudformation templates. However, the intrinsic function reference types and order are important here. As per the [AWS Documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-importvalue.html):

> You can't use the short form of !ImportValue when it contains a !Sub. Instead, you must use the full function name.

Therefore, structure your template like,

```
Properties:
    Bucket:
        Fn::Sub:
        - 'arn:aws:s3:::${BucketName}/prefix/*'
        - BucketName: !ImportValue VPCCommonBucket
```

Also, as your probably aware, to use the import function you must have [declared the resource an output](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/outputs-section-structure.html) in a separate cloudformation template. Here's an AWS provided [walk-through](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/walkthrough-crossstackref.html) if you get stuck.

Comment: No, that's not at all how you use ImportValue.  ImportValue is to import a previously exported variable in another stack.  Your code would attempt to import a variable named `arn:aws:s3:::${BucketName}/prefix/*` and inserting the name of the Parameter `BucketName` into the appropriate place.  That would give you an arn based off of the BucketName, but it's not getting the BucketName from CF exports.

Comment: @UtahJarhead answer updated, just swap the values around.

Comment: Ah....  OK, I didn't realize you can create variables on the fly like that.  Outstanding stuff!