# CloudFormation stack not triggering AWS Lambda from an S3 upload

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation

I'm using CloudFormation to deploy a stack, whereby a file upload to an existing S3 bucket and object triggers a Lambda function. The stack deploys without errors, however in the UI the connection between the S3 and Lambda resource is not shown, therefore a triggering cannot take place.

I've seen quite a few posts already regarding this topic, all with different flavours to the setup I require. In addition, I have seen the *!ImportValue* to use, as seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61290926/insert-a-cloudformation-importvalue-similar-to-how-you-can-insert-a-parameter), however the parameter *Bucket* is not recognised.

As mentioned already, the S3 bucket and object exist already, so I need to somehow reference an already existing resource in my template.yml. The current status is:

```yaml
      MyTrigger:
        Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
        Properties:
          FunctionName: !Ref LambdaModuleName
          CodeUri: src/my_module
          Handler: app.lambda_handler
          Runtime: python3.9
          MemorySize: 7500
          Timeout: 600
          ReservedConcurrentExecutions: 1
    
          Policies:
            - AWSLambdaExecute
            - AWSLambdaVPCAccessExecutionRole
            - Statement:
                - Sid: StagingS3DeleteCreate
                  Effect: Allow
                  Action:
                    - s3:DeleteObject*
                    - s3:PutObject*
                  Resource:
                    - arn:aws:s3:::bucket1/folder1/folder2/*
                - Sid: StagingS3List
                  Effect: Allow
                  Action:
                    - s3:List*
                  Resource:
                    - arn:aws:s3:::*
    
      # Permissions
      AllowS3ToCallLambdaPermission:
        Type: AWS::Lambda::Permission
        Properties:
          Action: 'lambda:InvokeFunction'
          FunctionName: !Ref MyTrigger
          Principal: s3.amazonaws.com
          SourceArn: arn:aws:s3:::bucket1/folder1/folder2/
```

My question is how can deploy a stack and reference this existing bucket and object, so that it triggers the Lambda upon a file upload?

**UPDATE**

Added:

```
  StagingBucket:
    Type: "AWS::S3::Bucket"
    DeletionPolicy: Retain
    Properties:
      BucketName: !Ref S3SourceBucket
```

where:

```
  S3SourceBucket:
    Type: String
    Default: "mybucket"
```

Answer (score 1):

You have set the IAM permissions, but not actually enabled the notifications.

The [S3 Bucket Notification Configuration](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-s3-bucket-notificationconfig.html) is a property of the S3 bucket itself.  You won't be able to add it to a bucket that is not part of this stack.  You can fix this by [importing](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/resource-import.html) the existing `AWS::S3::Bucket` resource so that it's part of, and managed by, the stack.

Once the existing bucket has been imported into the stack, you can set its [LambdaConfiguration](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-s3-bucket-notificationconfig-lambdaconfig.html), which tells S3 which Lambda to invoke and when.

Comment: Thank you for that. I added a bucket resource (see Edit above), but to no avail, as the stack won't deploy. I wanted to add this first before making the link with the Lambda. Do you know where am I going wrong?

Comment: @pymat  Did you follow the resource import instructions linked in the answer?  Simply adding an existing bucket by name won't work.  Also, bucket names cannot contain the `/` character.

Comment: Yes I took a look at that and saw the examples whereby this was incorporated in the template.yml (as per my example) above. I used just the bucket instead of the object too, but it didn't deploy.

Comment: going by the documentation, I get CREATE_FAILED bucket exists. Obviously the bucket is already there, but I'm not sure why it just doesn't import. In the above, I changed to "Default: bucketxyz" and removed the subfolders.

Comment: @pymat  Importing a resource to a stack involves several steps using the CLI or Console.  Specifically, you create and execute a CloudFormation change set of the type `--change-set-type IMPORT`.  The docs referenced in the answer have [step-by-step examples](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/resource-import-existing-stack.html).

Comment: thanks, I created a new ticket that is more specific: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62548918/specifying-an-s3-bucket-when-deploying-a-cloudformation-template

Comment: @pymat I have answered your [follow-up question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72615501/confusion-with-aws-resources-to-import-and-template-url).